# ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED when trying to access https site hosted by IIS 8.5 / 2012 R2 by IP Address in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

Warning: This question is largely academic.

I have a website in IIS 8.5, with an HTTPS binding on port 8443. The relevant netsh lines are:

```
IP:port                      : 0.0.0.0:8443
Certificate Hash             : 887250f4acef494ef4583e8dc8f1c7b5a40a90ed
Application ID               : {4dc3e181-e14b-4a21-b022-59fc669b0914}
Certificate Store Name       : My
Verify Client Certificate Revocation : Enabled
Verify Revocation Using Cached Client Certificate Only : Disabled
Usage Check                  : Enabled
Revocation Freshness Time    : 0
URL Retrieval Timeout        : 0
Ctl Identifier               : (null)
Ctl Store Name               : (null)
DS Mapper Usage              : Disabled
Negotiate Client Certificate : Disabled
```

In Firefox or Internet Explorer, I can access the site without issue using either `https://192.0.2.4:8443/` or `https://hostname:8443/`. In Google Chrome, I can only access the site using `https://hostname:8443`. Attempts to access the site as `https://192.0.2.4:8443/` return an error page with this text:

```
The webpage at `https://192.0.2.4:8443/` might be temporarily down or
it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED
```

The client machine is using Windows 7 64-bit, with Google Chrome Version 41.0.2272.101 m.

The server is Windows 2012R2. For testing purposes, Windows Firewall is offf and no antivirus software is installed on the server. I've looked in the event logs on the server, and I see no recorded error in the Application or System logs.

Any insights are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.